# Create a key:value pair dynamically

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I have the following groovy-script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy 
def files = [ 
    'file-1.bat' :  
        [       
            'content-1-1', 
            'content-1-2', 
            'content-1-3' 
        ],      
    'file-1' : 
        [       
            'content-unix-1-1', 
            'content-unix-1-2', 
            'content-unix-1-3', 
        ],      

    'file-2.bat' :  
        [       
            'content-2-1', 
            'content-2-2', 
            'content-2-3' 
        ],      
    'file-2' : 
        [       
            'content-unix-2-1', 
            'content-unix-2-2', 
            'content-unix-2-3', 
        ],      
] 

files.each { 
    file_key, file_value -> println file_key; 
    file_value.each { 
        file_content -> println "\t"+file_content; 
        files[ file_key ] = [file_content : true]; 
    }   
} 

println ' Upgraded content'; 

files.each { 
    file_key, file_value -> println file_key; 
    file_value.each { 
        file_content -> println "\t"+file_content; 
    }   
}
```

The following lines causes my problems:

```
files[ file_key ] = [file_content : true];
```

What I want to do is to create for every entry in the map also the true part of the key:value pair...I know that I didn't define the list in that way...
I've tried to enhance the map by using files[file_key].put(key, value); but this does not work...Maybe I'm thinking in a complete wrong direction...
The background of that construct is that in the files (file-1.bat, file-1 etc.) I will check the existence of the contents given as a Map

```
'file-1.bat' : [       
     'content-1-1', 
     'content-1-2', 
     'content-1-3' 
 ],
```

I could do the following:

```
'file-1.bat' : [       
     'content-1-1' : false, 
     'content-1-2' : false, 
     'content-1-3' : false, 
 ],
```

but that's exactly what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in thinking that `put()` will solve your issue, but you cannot put a map element into a list. You need to first create a map that can be `put` into, then assign the resulting map as the output.

For example:

```
files.each { 
    file_key, file_value -> println file_key; 
    def file_map = [:]; 
    file_value.each { 
        file_content -> println "\t"+file_content; 
        file_map.put(file_content, true); 
    }
    files[ file_key ] = file_map; 
}
```

Comment: Used [http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/) to verify this; very handy.